# Why are new versions of SE Android app released so often?

Tags: discussion, android-app

I've noticed that releases of new versions of the SE Android app happen very often. Sometimes there's a new version every day, sometimes there's a few days gaps.

I'm not saying this is a bad thing but it does stand out. The releases happen much more often than any other app I've been using.

Is there any particular reason behind such a short release cycle? How is it managed (developed/tested) to achieve that?

Comment: Even web version is updated frequently on daily basis. So they do the same with the app. May be new version for every [status-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app+status-completed).

Comment: That's true. But website updates are more transparent to users. It's more noticable that the app is upgraded.

Comment: I believe that [this comment](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/#comment-86658) by [Kevin Montrose](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose) on the Stack Exchange blog pretty much answers this:

`"...we’re in the post-1.0 squashing bugs phase of things, so we’re doing pretty regular updates."`

Comment: At least for me, the Android app seems about as stable as a blind drunkard on a unicycle, so I'm not really surprised by frequent bugfix updates. I just wish they'd eventually get it to a state where I could actually use it for more than a few minutes without it crashing.

Comment: Worthy as answer, @Lix, with that quote as sort of official response. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - It started off as an answer - but other than the quote there really isn't anything more to say so I didn't feel that it warranted a question id :P

Answer (score 3):

As people use the app they will find bugs with it and (hopefully) report them. As those bugs get fixed, a new version of the app (hopefully) with those bugs fixed will be released (I actually found another bug while writing this answer). This happens quite a bit with the Facebook app, they seem to have an update nearly everyday.

AFAIK this wouldn't be the case for the iOS version of the app because each update that is pushed can take anywhere from a day to four or five days (sometimes longer) to be vetted and released onto the Apple store, while Android apps can be pushed and released onto the Google Play Store in a few hours. So the Android app can be updated more often to fix bugs.